# event for JQuery DataTable Sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatable, datatables

I'm running into a problem with Jquery datatables where sort order doesn't get reflected.

I have one table on my page and there are 2 tabs on the page that allow users to switch from a plain table view to a grouped table view. I want to sort on col index 0 and 5 when users are in Grouped view but only on col 5 when they are in List view.

My question is less related to the code that has been written but more a general one. I'd like to know which datatable event is suitable for me to write function for Grouping and sorting changes when users click on Tabs.

should it be drawCallback? or something else?

Comment: Add your`code` in Question

Comment: [Look this example](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/jqueryUI.html)

Comment: listen on the `order` or `draw` events, iie. `order.dt` / `draw.dt` -> start here https://datatables.net/reference/event/order